# processing - OpenCV library confusion

Tags: opencv, processing

I am having a bit of trouble understanding OpenCV with processing. It tells me OpenCV is already pre-installed/installed, yet it can't detect its libraries for object creation. Even manual installation by copying the folder and adding it under my sketchbook -> libraries doesn't work. Library link: [OpenCV-processing](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing). Am I missing something? Thank you.
[image: Proof]
[image: Error]

Comment: Aren't you missing importing the library? I mean `import gab.opencv.*;`

Answer (score 0):

As @v.k. points out, you should be using importing the [OpenCV for Processing](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing)

```
import gab.opencv.*;
```

which is a more modern wrapper for OpenCV, not the old [UBAA OpenCV wrapper](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwjdnbSanfbHAhUCvxQKHZkHDvE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fubaa.net%2Fshared%2Fprocessing%2Fopencv%2F&usg=AFQjCNFptGIHaRwWnz_PUa5tEHG_6bA7-Q&sig2=L4i0ADIxIpbF7j8Todtrpw&bvm=bv.102537793,d.d24)(`hypermedia.video.*`)

Processing's Add Library tool should've installed the library correctly for you. Alternatively you can grab the latest opencv_processing.zip from the [releases page](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing/releases) and unzip it in Documents/Processing/libraries.

You should have a structure like this in Documents/Processing/libraries/opencv_processing:

```
├── data
│   └── README
├── examples
│   ├── BackgroundSubtraction
│   │   ├── BackgroundSubtraction.pde
│   │   └── data
│   │       └── street.mov
│   ├── BrightestPoint
│   │   ├── BrightestPoint.pde
│   │   └── robot_light.jpg
│   ├── BrightnessContrast
│   │   ├── BrightnessContrast.pde
│   │   └── test.jpg
│   ├── CalibrationDemo
│   │   ├── CalibrationDemo.pde
│   │   └── data
│   │       └── checkerboard.jpg
│   ├── ColorChannels
│   │   ├── ColorChannels.pde
│   │   └── green_object.png
│   ├── DepthFromStereo
│   │   ├── DepthFromStereo.pde
│   │   ├── scene_l.jpg
│   │   └── scene_r.jpg
│   ├── DilationAndErosion
│   │   ├── DilationAndErosion.pde
│   │   ├── line_drawing.jpg
│   │   └── pen_sketch.jpg
│   ├── FaceDetection
│   │   ├── FaceDetection.pde
│   │   └── data
│   │       ├── test.jpg
│   │       ├── test.png
│   │       ├── testImage.png
│   │       └── transparent_test.png
│   ├── FilterImages
│   │   ├── FilterImages.pde
│   │   └── test.jpg
│   ├── FindContours
│   │   ├── FindContours.pde
│   │   └── test.jpg
│   ├── FindEdges
│   │   ├── FindEdges.pde
│   │   └── test.jpg
│   ├── FindHistogram
│   │   ├── FindHistogram.pde
│   │   └── test.jpg
│   ├── HistogramSkinDetection
│   │   ├── HistogramSkinDetection.pde
│   │   └── data
│   │       ├── cb-cr.png
│   │       └── test.jpg
│   ├── HoughLineDetection
│   │   ├── HoughLineDetection.pde
│   │   └── film_scan.jpg
│   ├── HueRangeSelection
│   │   ├── HueRangeSelection.pde
│   │   ├── colored_balls.jpg
│   │   └── rainbow.jpg
│   ├── ImageDiff
│   │   ├── ImageDiff.pde
│   │   ├── after.jpg
│   │   └── before.jpg
│   ├── LiveCamTest
│   │   ├── LiveCamTest.pde
│   │   └── data
│   │       └── haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
│   ├── LoadAndDisplayImage
│   │   ├── LoadAndDisplayImage.pde
│   │   └── data
│   │       ├── test.jpg
│   │       └── test.png
│   ├── LumaVsGray
│   │   ├── LumaVsGray.pde
│   │   └── flashlight.jpg
│   ├── MarkerDetection
│   │   ├── MarkerDetection.pde
│   │   └── marker_test.jpg
│   ├── RegionOfInterest
│   │   ├── RegionOfInterest.pde
│   │   └── test.jpg
│   ├── WarpPerspective
│   │   ├── WarpPerspective.pde
│   │   └── cards.png
│   └── WorkingWithColorImages
│       ├── WorkingWithColorImages.pde
│       └── test.jpg
├── library
│   ├── cascade-files
│   │   ├── haarcascade_clock.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_eye.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_fullbody.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_lowerbody.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_small.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_mcs_leftear.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_mcs_lefteye.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_mcs_rightear.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_mcs_righteye.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_profileface.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml
│   │   ├── haarcascade_upperbody.xml
│   │   ├── hogcascade_pedestrians.xml
│   │   └── lbpcascade_frontalface.xml
│   ├── linux32
│   │   ├── libopencv_calib3d.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_contrib.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_contrib.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_core.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_core.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_core.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_features2d.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_features2d.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_flann.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_flann.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_flann.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_gpu.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_gpu.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_highgui.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_imgproc.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_java245.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_legacy.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_legacy.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_ml.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_ml.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_ml.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_nonfree.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_objdetect.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_photo.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_photo.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_photo.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_superres.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_superres.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_superres.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_ts.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_ts.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_ts.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_video.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_video.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_video.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_videostab.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_videostab.so.2.4
│   │   └── libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.5
│   ├── linux64
│   │   ├── libopencv_calib3d.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_contrib.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_contrib.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_core.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_core.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_core.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_features2d.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_features2d.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_flann.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_flann.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_flann.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_gpu.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_gpu.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_highgui.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_imgproc.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_java245.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_legacy.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_legacy.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_ml.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_ml.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_ml.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_nonfree.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_objdetect.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_photo.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_photo.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_photo.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_stitching.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_stitching.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_superres.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_superres.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_superres.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_ts.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_ts.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_ts.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_video.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_video.so.2.4
│   │   ├── libopencv_video.so.2.4.5
│   │   ├── libopencv_videostab.so
│   │   ├── libopencv_videostab.so.2.4
│   │   └── libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.5
│   ├── macosx64
│   │   ├── libopencv_calib3d.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_calib3d.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_calib3d.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_contrib.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_contrib.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_contrib.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_core.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_core.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_core.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_features2d.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_features2d.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_features2d.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_flann.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_flann.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_flann.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_gpu.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_gpu.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_gpu.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_haartraining_engine.a
│   │   ├── libopencv_highgui.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_highgui.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_imgproc.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_imgproc.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_java245.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_legacy.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_legacy.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_legacy.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_ml.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_ml.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_ml.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_nonfree.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_nonfree.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_nonfree.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_objdetect.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_objdetect.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_objdetect.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_ocl.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_ocl.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_ocl.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_photo.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_photo.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_photo.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_stitching.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_stitching.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_stitching.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_superres.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_superres.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_superres.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_ts.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_ts.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_ts.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_video.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_video.2.4.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_video.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_videostab.2.4.5.dylib
│   │   ├── libopencv_videostab.2.4.dylib
│   │   └── libopencv_videostab.dylib
│   ├── opencv-245.jar
│   ├── opencv_processing.jar
│   ├── windows32
│   │   └── opencv_java245.dll
│   └── windows64
│       └── opencv_java245.dll
├── library.properties
├── reference
│   ├── allclasses-frame.html
│   ├── allclasses-noframe.html
│   ├── constant-values.html
│   ├── deprecated-list.html
│   ├── gab
│   │   └── opencv
│   │       ├── Contour.html
│   │       ├── ContourComparator.html
│   │       ├── Histogram.html
│   │       ├── Line.html
│   │       ├── OpenCV.html
│   │       ├── package-frame.html
│   │       ├── package-summary.html
│   │       └── package-tree.html
│   ├── help-doc.html
│   ├── index-all.html
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── overview-tree.html
│   ├── package-list
│   ├── resources
│   │   └── inherit.gif
│   └── stylesheet.css
└── src
    └── gab
        └── opencv
            ├── Contour.java
            ├── ContourComparator.java
            ├── Histogram.java
            ├── Line.java
            └── OpenCV.java
```